# React, Redux clear state using Life Cycle Method

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, lifecycle, unmount

EDIT 9/5/17:
It turns out I had an issue with a different part of my react code in React that led me to believe that my stack was not properly resetting. One of the few components I was rendering on the /Profile page was calling array.length on an empty array, and that error was preventing my code from running and my browsers was freezing. Thanks for looking regardless

I am attempting to reset the state of an object (let's call it UID) in my store when a component unmounts.

The initial state of UID is an empty string, when a user clicks on a username (a user that's made a post) I am rendering a profile component, but before the profile component is rendered, I am populating the UID, and rendering a profile component that matches the UID.

What I'd like to do now is clear the UID when the Profile component unmounts, so if a user clicks on a different user name, I can render a different profile.

Profile component:

```
class Profile extends Component {
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.clearUserUid()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid id="profile">

        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column className='profileheader'>
            <ProfileHeader />
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>

          <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column>
              <AddSocial/>
              <ListOfSocialLinks/>
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>

         </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Action

```
export const clearUserUid = uid => ({
  type: 'CLEAR_UID', payload: ''
})
```

Reducer:

```
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function (userUid = initialState.userUid, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CLEAR_UID':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return userUid;
  }
```

}

Initial State

```
userUid: '',
```

component listening to userUid

```
class ListOfSocialLinks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.userUid && this.props.userUid.length > 0) {
      firebase.database().ref(`users/${this.props.userUid}/social`).on('value', snapshot => this.props.fetchSocial(snapshot.val()));
    }
    else {
      firebase.database().ref(`users/${this.props.userData.uid}`).on('value', snapshot => {
       return this.props.fetchSocial(snapshot.val())
       })
     }
  }


  render() {
    const { social, userData } = this.props;
    return (<div className="social"> { this.renderSocial(social, userData) }</div>);
   }
}
```

userData.uid is always available for the user to view their own profile.

clearUserUid action runs, and the state of my store changes to an empty string, but, when I click on a different user after the profile component unmounts, I get an error on the page.

How can I properly reset the state of the store to an empty string?

Comment: have u tried to use `null` instead of an empty string

Comment: @Amr I just edited my post and added the code that's listening to changes to userUid. I tried retuning null as the payload for, but I cannot call length on a null object so my component does not render

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing some code in your example but my guess is that the component itself is actually not unmounting. When properties change through redux, it doesn't mount/unmount, it just re-renders.

There are a few events that you can bolt into. My suggestion is to use componentWillUpdate to see that the paramater uid has changed and to trigger the clear.

```
// Invoked whenever there is a prop change
// Called BEFORE render
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Not called for the initial render
    // Previous props can be accessed by this.props
    // Calling setState here does not trigger an an additional re-render
}

// Called IMMEDIATELY BEFORE a render
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    // You cannot use this.setState() in this method
}

// Called IMMEDIATELY AFTER a render
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
}
```

If this is not the case, you may need to re-work the question with more of an example.

Comment: I edited my post again reflecting this. It turns out the state was changing. I had an issue else where in my code that was causing an error. Thanks for the suggestions on the lifecycle methods. I'll look over them just for learning sake.